# Markov chains with “clustered” stationary distributions

Tags: markov-chains

Are there any canonical or well-known Markov chains whose stationary distributions are basically clustered into two or more components? Obviously, it is easy to create one, but I’m wondering if there are any popular ones from the literature; the most popular ones I come across either have absorbing states (gamblers ruin) or aren’t particularly clustered (Ehrenfest urns, M/M/1 queues)